# How to tell ServiceStack not to drop nulls in my list?

Tags: c#, json, datetime, servicestack

I have this problem where a null datetime in a list is not being serialized/deserialized properly.

see this sample code:

```
internal class WrapperNullableDateTimeList
{
    public List<DateTime?> MyList { get; set; }
}

public void T14_Should_skip_output_nullable_datetime_in_list_TODO_THIS_IS_WRONG()
     {
         WrapperNullableDateTimeList input = new WrapperNullableDateTimeList();
         input.MyList = new List<DateTime?>()
         {
           new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
           null,
           new DateTime(2000, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
         };

         JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
         var serializer = new JsonSerializer<WrapperNullableDateTimeList>();
         string serializedInput = serializer.SerializeToString(input);

         WrapperNullableDateTimeList output = serializer.DeserializeFromString(serializedInput);

         output.MyList.Count.Should().Be(3); // Fails here! The 'null' DateTime in the list is dropped
     }
```

Any ideas?
BTW, I printed the serializedInput (json), and it looks like this:

> {"MyList":["2000-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",null,"2000-12-31T00:00:00.0000000Z"]}

I have my JsConfig to include null values... so what gives?

Answer (score 2):

This works in the latest version of ServiceStack:

```
using (JsConfig.With(new Config { includeNullValues = true }))
{
    var dto = new WrapperNullableDateTimeList
    {
        MyList = new List<DateTime?>
        {
            new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            null,
            new DateTime(2000, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
        }
    };

    var json = dto.ToJson();
    json.Print();

    Assert.That(json, Is.EqualTo(
      @"{""MyList"":[""\/Date(946684800000)\/"",null,""\/Date(978220800000)\/""]}"));

    var fromJson = json.FromJson<WrapperNullableDateTimeList>();

    Assert.That(fromJson.MyList.Count, Is.EqualTo(dto.MyList.Count));
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm still using the 3.9x version... as there are licensing costs with the 4.x versions.

Comment: @Raymond Yes [v4 is a commercial release](https://servicestack.net/text#pricing) but does have [free quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas).